# Highcharts NaN values in y-axis after isNaN check

Tags: highcharts

A couple of my series charts are not rendering in certain regions because of NaN values. I've checked my datapoints coming back from the server, and none of my points are coming back as anything but integers. There seems to be no rhyme or reason as to why certain percentages in the tooltip return NaN.N% or 0.00%. I could hover over a point and the tooltip says "0 (0.00%)" then hover over a point a little further across the chart and have it say "5 (NaN.N%)". I've tried to insert an NaN check in the formatter option without any change. Here is my function (as CoffeeScript):

```
labels: {
  formatter: -> return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + (isNaN(this.value) ? 0.00 : this.value) + '%'
}
```

Just to re-iterate, the tooltips rendering is never the issue and the actual number count rendering in the tooltip is never the issue, it's just the y-axis lines, percentages in the tooltips, and the series lines that are the issues. Here are a couple examples of what I'm seeing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHZJc.jpg

Comment: I had observed a similar issue when I was working with an unsupported version of jQuery (I was using 1.8 while the version of highcharts that I was on, only supported till 1.7). Appears that the latest highcharts lib supports 1.8 http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility you can give a try upgrading your highcharts too. For best help please post a jsFiddle reproduction or some more code of your chart, along with the json of the data that is being pushed into the chart

Comment: Upgrading both jQuery and Highstock (yes, I realized we were using Highstock instead of Highcharts) did help clean things up a bit, but it's unfortunately still not rendering parts of the chart. I re-created it as best I could in jsFiddle, the chart renders but it's complaining of invalid dates? Not sure what's going on there, but the chart DOES render on the page I'm working on and will show data once I adjust the dates forward about a month. Maybe besides the dates issue someone can see any glaring mistakes I'm making?

http://jsfiddle.net/ELrpj/

Thank you very much ahead of time!